# python Re.search for a password symbol check program (password validation)

Tags: python, password-checker

I'm making a program to check password strength. The password must have uppercase letters, lowercase letters, allowed symbols and numbers. I have been able to get the rest of the program to work(useing the re.search(r'[a-z],password  structure) I shortened the problem area to these few lines but cannot get this part to work. Should I be using something different to re.search?

```
    import re
    symbols = ["!","(",")","£","^"]
    password = input("password")
    if re.search(r'[symbols]',password):
      print("ok")
    else:
      print("no")
```

Comment: You can't just expect random names to get interpolated into your string. Try something like `'[{}]'.format(symbols)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Just specify all your symbols inside the regex range:

```
password_valid = bool(re.search(r'[!()£^]', password))
```

Inside `[..]` most regex metacharacters [lose their special meaning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), just watch out for the `^` in the first position and for the character classes, like `\w`.

If you take care to prevent those cases, you can keep symbols in the list, and use it like:

```
symbols = ["!", "(", ")", "£", "^"]
password_valid = bool(re.search(r'[{}]'.format(''.join(symbols)), password))
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution could be something like this

```
import re
def is_password_valid(password):
    return bool(re.search('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[+\-*\/])(?=.*[!()£^])', password))
```

or simpler to understand

```
import re
def is_password_valid(pas):
    is_ok1 = bool(re.search("[a-z]",pas))
    is_ok2 = bool(re.search("[A-Z]",pas))
    is_ok3 = bool(re.search("[0-9]",pas))
    is_ok4 = bool(re.search("[+\-*\/!()£^]",pas))        
    return is_ok1 and is_ok2 and is_ok3 and is_ok4
```